# How can show amount in words in crystal report !

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I m working on windows form application. I need to show amount in words in crystal report.
How can show amount in words in crystal report ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write custom property in the class object (if you are binding it to object datasource) which returns the value of amount in words.

If you are binding it to table or output from stored procedure then you need to add a column to the table in result set and populate it with the value of amount in words.

Now you can bind the label to column/property to show amount in words.

EDIT: code example (hope this helps you)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Expenses e = new Expenses();
        e.Total = 137313959;
        Console.WriteLine(e.TotalInWords);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class Expenses
    {
        public int Total
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string TotalInWords
        {
            get
            {
                return ConvertToWords(Total);
            }
        }

        private static string ConvertToWords(int amount)
        {
            string s = amount + "";
            int g = (s.Length / 3);//groups of three digits
            int a = (s.Length % 3);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            if (g == 0) //only three or less digits
            {
                sb.Append(ConvertToHunderds(s, false));
            }
            else
            {
                if (a > 0)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1} ", ConvertToHunderds(s.Substring(0, a),
                             false), groups[g]);
                }

                int idx = a;

                while (g > 0)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat(" {0} {1} ", ConvertToHunderds(s.Substring(a, 3), 
                                     g == 1), groups[--g]);
                    a += 3;
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private static string ConvertToHunderds(string s,bool useAnd)
        {
            char[] c =new char[s.Length];

            for (int i = s.Length-1,j=0; i >=0 && j<c.Length; j++, i--)
            {
                c[j] = s[i];
            }

            if (c.Length == 3)
            {
                if (c[2] == '0')
                    return string.Format("{0}{1}", (useAnd ? "and " : ""), GetTens(c[1], 
                             c[0]));
                else
                    return string.Format("{0} hundred {1} {2}", digits[((int)c[2]) -
                                       48],
                        (useAnd ? "and" : ""),
                        GetTens(c[1], c[0]));
            }
            else if(c.Length==2)
            {
                return useAnd ? "and " : "" + GetTens(c[1], c[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                return digits[((int)c[0]) - 48];
            }
        }

        private static string GetTens(char ten, char one)
        {
            if (one == '0')
                if (ten == '1')
                    return eleven2nineteen[((int)ten) - 49];
                else
                    return tens[((int)ten) - 49];

            if(ten=='1')
                return  eleven2nineteen[((int)one) - 49];

            return tens[((int)ten) - 49] //because tens[0] = 10 so subtract 49 (ascii 1)
                + " " 
                + digits[((int)one) - 48];
        }

        private static string[] groups = new[] { ""/*hundreds group*/, "thousand", 
                             "million", "billion", "trilliion" };
        private static string[] digits = new[] { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four",
                  "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };
        private static string[] eleven2nineteen = new[] { "eleven", "twelve", 
                  "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", 
                   "eighteen", "nineteen" };
        private static string[] tens = new[] { "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "fourty", 
              "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };
    }
```

this outputs:

```
one hunderd  thirty seven million  three hunderd  thirteen thousand  nine 
hundred and fifty nine
```

PS:- This is for illustration purpose only. Please if (ever) you use it use proper exception handling etc.

Comment: I have amount in Int type. That I want to in words.

Answer (score 2):

Make a formula field in the report and use the ToWords built in function

Answer (score 2):

try using this

```
IF {#TOTAL}<100 OR Remainder ({#TOTAL},100 )=0 then
''& ProperCase (towords ({#TOTAL},0))& 'Only ' 
ELSE
'' & ProperCase (towords ({#TOTAL}-Remainder ({#TOTAL},100 ),0)) & ' & ' & ProperCase(ToWords (Remainder ({#TOTAL},100 ),0))&' Only'
```